# Why can a https website with a mismatching certificate domain name be marked as 'secure' by browser?

Tags: ssl, browser, https, x509certificate

I have basic knowledge of SSL and can configure web site https certificate.
I used to believe

> A 'secure' https website much have a matching(at least a wildcard
> matching) certificate domain name

until today.

Take [google.com](https://www.google.com/) as example:

- By Chrome certificate viewer:

[image]

- By openssl

```sh
openssl s_client -connect google.com
```

Got same result:

> ... depth=0 CN = *.google.com ...

This is just woking as expected for me.

But I just found(which was mistake when expecting [cn.bing.com](https://cn.bing.com/) actually) a website [bing.cn](https://bing.cn/),

- By Chrome certificate viewer:

[image]

- By openssl

```sh
openssl s_client -connect bing.cn
```

Got different result:

> ... depth=0 CN = *.wordpress.com ...

And this is beyond my knowledge. Could you explain

1. Why can the domain name be different with certificate but still is secure?
2. Why does gui version(`tls.automattic.com`) and command version(`*.wordpress.com`) show different certificate  domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subject` field is obsoleted by all modern browsers and they look for authorized names in `Subject Alternative Name` certificate extension:

[image]

and `bing.cn` is authorized by this certificate. In fact, this certificate is allowed to represent any name listed in this extension.